# Xcode 7 Asset Catalog's image sets weird status icons

Tags: iphone, xcode, asset-catalog

what do these icons mean beside each image set in the asset catalog ?

I googled for these icons but to no avail ...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

These are shown to immediately let you know that the icons are the type of AppIcon, LaunchImage and normal image (in the order you provided in the screenshot). This way, just via looking at the icons you can see which one is e.g. LaunchImage.